# How to use Māori macrons in KDE Plasma / Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, input-language

I've used Ubuntu for several years & are currently using Ubuntu 22.04 - Jammy Jellyfish on a Lenovo Carbon X1.

I live in New Zealand & use Māori phrases in my correspondence. The Māori language uses macrons to denote a long vowel sound.

In the past I've used [this page/ guide to setup Māori on my Ubuntu machines](https://kupu.maori.nz/about/macrons-keyboard-setup#linux), with no issues. I could hold down the Alt-Right key & the vowel to add a macron to that vowel.

The default desktop for Ubuntu 22.04 has had some stability issues, so I decided to try KDE Plasma.

I like KDE Plasma & have [enabled the Compose (Alt-Right) key](https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/ComposeKey#Plasma_Workspace) so I can macrons by going `Compose + underscore` followed by the `vowel`.

However, this is clunky compared to the standard Ubuntu approach of `Alt-Right + vowel`.

Has anyone found a way of setting up KDE Plasma / kubuntu to enter Māori macrons with the easier Ubuntu method?

Comment: The Maori keyboard layout is available also when you use a KDE DE, isn't it? What's the reason why you don't make use of it like you previously did on standard Ubuntu?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - could you walk me through how to add this please, I haven't been able to find the option.

Comment: I can't since I don't have access to any KDE installation ATM.

Answer (score 0):

Long time since the post, but ... oh well. I have trouble with the maori keyboard as well. If I use X11, the left alt key gets screwed up and I can't alt tab between windows or ctrl-alt fx to a tty. Which you need to do everytime the screen locker fails and you can't wake the machine. If I use wayland, I can alt tab and right-alt + vowel, but there is something else that annoys me (I forget - using x at the moment) and the ctrl-alt Fx doesn't work either. But Alt-tab does. So I still can't escape screen locker failure hell.

But it is better than X11.

If I remove the maori keyboard, everything works - apart from the maori macrons of course.

> The Maori keyboard layout is available also when you use a KDE DE, isn't it? What's the reason why you don't make use of it like you previously did on standard Ubuntu?

Because - as stated - it does not work. right-alt vowel doesn't work in X11 at least. Something about the keyboard is interfering with the ctrl key in wayland, and is just off in X11.